# Unable to SSH into EC2 Ubuntu Instance port 22:Connection Refused

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I created EC2 Ubuntu Instance, when the status check was clear, I tried following command.

`chmod -400 key.pem`

&

`ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@ip_address`

which gave following error

`ssh: connect to host ip_address port 22: Connection refused`

Then I tried rebooting the Instance but the error was still there.I tried

`telnet ip_address 22`

which gave me the same error

`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

I already follwed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026148/running-ec2-instance-suddenly-refuses-ssh-connection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447438/ec2-ssh-port-22-connection-refused-even-though-previously-worked)   following links but none worked:

Please tell me how do I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

For EC2, first check your network security groups. Normally outbound is open, but inbound is completely closed. Did you set up port 22 and set it either to your IP address or open?

Also, check what happens when you type `sudo service ssh restart`. No error message is usually good.

Do you have more than one instance? Can you ssh from one to the other?

Also, make sure you are using the public IP address

Comment: My inbound is open on port 22 and 80 and outbound open for all. My inbound source is anywhere. My `ssh` works fine and no error on restarting.

Comment: Cool - it will cost only cents to create another instance and troubleshoot by  ssh between them and also did you try everything on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P29ZHu_feU ?

Comment: What do you do if there is an error on restarting? I got `Unit ssh.service not found` on my ubuntu PC

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with AWS